# Passing a 2d array with pointers and accessing it gives segmentation fault

Tags: c

im trying to pass a 2D array from main to a function and trying to print it letter by letter
but it keeps giving me segmentation fault

note: the question im trying to solve as mentioned a function with parameter { ArrPrintMatrix(char *(p)[7]) }
so help me by keeping the above thing in mind

```
    #include<stdio.h>
ArrPrintMatrix(char **p,int n) {
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<10;j++) {
            printf("%c ",p[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

main() {
    int i;
    char c[2][10];
    puts("enter two strings");
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    scanf("%s",c[i]);

    ArrPrintMatrix((char **) c,2);
}
```

Comment: a `char[n][m]` is not synonymous with `char**`. Whatever tutorial or book said otherwise... burn it.

Comment: This is pretty unsafe.  You've made a 2d array of char, and then you call scanf on a string. This is asking for segfault overruns.  And As Whoz said, char[][] is not char**.

Answer (score 1):

You should use char `p[2][10]` not `char** p`

The following `code` could work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void ArrPrintMatrix(char p[2][10], int n) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        printf("%s\n",p[i]);
}

int main() {
    int i;
    char c[2][10];
    puts("enter two strings");
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
        scanf("%s",c[i]);

    ArrPrintMatrix(c,2);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to change the type of the p var in the print function, and you should also set the array to zero so if the strings that are printing are less than 10 chars with terminator- garbage values are not displayed.

```
void ArrPrintMatrix(char p[][10],int n) {
int i,j;
for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
    for(j=0;j<10;j++) {
        printf("%c ",p[i][j]);
    }
  }
}

int main() {
 int i;
 char c[2][10]= {0};
 puts("enter two strings");
 for(i=0;i<2;i++)
 scanf("%s",c[i]);

 ArrPrintMatrix( c,2);
 return 0;
 }
```